# Adding element to nested vector

Tags: vector, clojure, io

i don't know how to get this done, maybe somebody could help me? I'd like to make something like this:

```
vector<int> L[MAX_V];
for(int i=1;i<N;++i){
    scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
    --u; --v;
    L[u].push_back(v);
    L[v].push_back(u);
}
```

,but in clojure language. So far I have come with something like this, but it's not working:

```
(defn LoadTree []
  (def n (read-string (read-line)))
  (def tree (atom (into [] (repeat n []))))
  (loop [x n]
    (when (> x 1)
      (let [input (read-string (str "[" (read-line) "]"))]
        (swap! (get @tree (dec (get input 0))) conj (dec (get input 1))) <-Error
        (swap! (get @tree (dec (get input 1))) conj (dec (get input 0))) <-Error
      (recur (dec x))
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: `swap!` should work directly on tree (not @tree). Then look at using one from the family of functions: `assoc`, `assoc-in`, `update`, `update-in`.

Comment: Also, it needs to be said: don't use `def` here! Use `let` to create local bindings.

Comment: Also note that the code you're trying to reproduce makes use of mutable objects. Instead of trying to directly reproduce this code, you should be trying to make use of immutable thinking. Atoms and local defs are "nuclear options", and you're using both here. It would be difficult to say exactly how you should be writing this without a bit more context.

Comment: I don't think context is really needed to understand how to implement this. It's fairly clear what the C code wants to do, and writing a Clojure function that produces the same output is not totally easy but has no particular unknowns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
(defn foo [num-reads size]
  (loop [i num-reads, r (vec (repeat size []))]
    (if (zero? i) 
      r
      (let [[u v] (repeatedly read)]
        (recur (dec i), (-> r (update u conj v) (update v conj u)))))))
```